# Classes: Function Use within the same Class

Tags: python, class

I'm sure this is well understood, but even the examples I see I have trouble understanding how to use functions defined within a particular class.

The simple example I've made is as follows (make a function `add_one` that adds 1 to a given input number and then use that function in another function `add_two`):

```
class TestPassingFunctions: 
    def __init__(self, number): 
        self.number = number

    def add_one(self, number):
        return number + 1

    def add_two(self, number):
        new_value = self.add_one(number) + 1
        return new_value

TestPassingFunctions.add_two(2)
```

This returns:

```
TypeError: add_two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
```

From what I've read, it looks the class is interpreting the `2` as the `self` parameter. As is probably obvious, I don't entirely understand when/how I should be using the initialization with `__init__`. Up until this point, I thought it should be used to propagate variable values through the class to be used by the different functions, but there's clearly some flaw in my use.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't created any instances of your class.... why would you expect it to work without an instance? If you want it to work without instances, then you probably don't want a class at all.

Comment: alternately you could make it a [`classmethod`](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize an object of type `TestPassingFunctions`. Do this like so:

```
test = TestPassingFunctions(1)
test.add_two(2)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. 

The question is because I'm trying to make a kivy app, but use the class functions within this class (the framework of kivy). 

Maybe this is becoming too much of an abstraction, but if within the class definition I wanted to add `100` to whatever the user submitted for `add_one` and then use that value new value for `add_two`, how could I go about doing that? This is really the functionality I'm after because I have some labels I'm updating in the app, but need to be transformed (from RSS feeds) - I was hoping to use a function for that modification.

Comment: @user6142489 I'm not so sure about that, but if you found my answer helpful, please press the green check under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate an instance of the class first:

```
a = TestPassingFunctions(1)
print(a.add_two(2))
```

Comment: There already is an answer to this question that provides that information

Comment: I solved it myself and I did not see an answer when I submitted mine. It does take a minute to put the code and correctly format it...

Comment: @mrCarnivore my apologies, the code just looked really similar

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to always create an instance, you can make the function a `classmethod` or a `staticmethod` (useful if you want classes for inheritance but not specifically to hold state (local variables associated with each instance))

```
class TestPassingFunctions: 

    @staticmethod #doesn't need anything else from the class
    def add_one(number):
        return number + 1

    @classmethod #may need to refer to the class (in this case to access cls.add_one)
    def add_two(cls, number):
        new_value = cls.add_one(number) + 1
        return new_value

TestPassingFunctions.add_two(2) #returns 4
```

*[Here's](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) a quick guide on the different types of methods you can use*

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the contents of class methods, static methods and regular methods of a class.

These methods are defined to be used as regular methods, with an instance of your class:

```
test = TestPassingFunctions(1)
test.add_two
```

If you want to call them without an instance, like `TestPassingFunctions.add_two(2)`, you should define them as static or class methods, with a decorator `@staticmethod` and without `self` as first parameter